# Python GC Counter - Rosalind

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I'm attempting to write a programme that will calculate the GC content in each of a series of sequences (input in fasta format) and then return the name of the sequence with the highest percentage and its GC percentage.
As per [this Rosalind problem.](http://rosalind.info/problems/gc/)

I've finally stopped getting error messages but my code doesn't appear to do anything. Does anyone have any idea why that might be?

```
#Define functions
#Calculate GC percentage 
def Percent(sequence):
G_count = sequence.count ('G')
C_count = sequence.count ('C')
Total_count = len(sequence)
GC_Sum = int(G_count) + int(C_count)
Percent_GC = GC_Sum / Total_count
Per_GC = (Percent_GC)*100
return Per_GC

Input = input ("Input Sequence")

#Fasta file into dictionary
fasta_dictionary = {}
sequence_name = ""
for line in Input:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    if line.startswith(">"):
        sequence_name = line[1:]
        if sequence_name not in fasta_dictionary:
            fasta_dictionary[sequence_name] = []
        continue
    sequence = line
    fasta_dictionary[sequence_name].append(sequence)

#Put GC values for each sequence into dictionary
dictionary = dict()
for sequence_name in fasta_dictionary:
dictionary[sequence_name] = float(Percent(sequence))

#Find highest
for sequence_name, sequence in fasta_dictionary.items():
    inverse = [(sequence, sequence_name) for sequence_name, sequence in dictionary.items()]
    highest_GC = max(inverse)[1]  

#Find sequence name
for sequence_name, sequence in fasta_dictionary.items():
        if sequence == highest_GC:
            print ((sequence_name) + ' ' + (highest_GC))
```

Comment: You don't seem to open your data file. From what I understand, `Input` is the _name_ of the data file, but not the data file itself. Try writing `with open(Input, 'r') as <name>:` and then: `for line in <name>:`. See what happens. (Also, if you're using Python 2.x, be careful of `GC_Sum / Total_count` because it involves _integer_ division.)

Comment: Also, please properly indent you python code. Indentation is syntactically important.

Comment: I lost some of the indents when I copied it onto here. They're right on the real file.

Answer (score 1):

So, Pier Paolo is correct change the first line to `with open()` and indent the rest of your code under that as shown below.

```
with open('/path/to/your/fasta.fasta', 'r') as Input:
   fasta_dictionary = {}
```

He is also correct on the division -- this should help inside your `Percent` function.  `Percent_GC = float(GC_Sum) / Total_count`

Instead of appending, just assign `sequence` as a string.

```
sequence = line
fasta_dictionary[sequence_name] = sequence
```

Next, when you are calling your `Percent` function, you are passing `sequence`, after you've exited the for loop where you define each `sequence` iteratively. You have them stored in a dictionary called `fasta_dictionary`, so change this piece of code.

```
for sequence_name in fasta_dictionary:
        dictionary[sequence_name] = float(Percent(fasta_dictionary[sequence_name]))
```

Finally, at the end, you are checking `if sequence == highest_GC:`.  This is what you're currently checking:

```
for sequence_name, sequence in fasta_dictionary.items():
            print sequence
```

prints a `str` of the actual sequence data.

```
'ATTGCGCTANANAGCTANANCGATAGANCACGATNGAGATAGACTATAGC'
```

and `highest_GC` is the "name" of the sequence

```
>sequence1
```

change that to read `if sequence_name == highest_GC`

Running your code with the changes above always printed the name of the sequence with the highest GC content %.  There are a lot of other unnecessary steps and repetitive code, but hopefully this gets you started.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for your GC problem would be to use the Counter higher-order data structure in python. It can automatically set and count your nucleotides for you such that you can just directly ask for the numbers to calculate as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

#set a var to hold your dna
myDna = ''
#open your Dna fasta
with open('myFasta', 'r') as data:
     for line in data:
          if '>' in line:
               continue
          myDna += line.strip()

#Now count your dna
myNucleotideCounts = Counter(myDna)

#calculate GC content
myGC = (myNucleotideCounts['G'] + myNucleotideCounts['C']) / float(len(myDna))

print('Dna GC Content = {0}'.format(myGC))
```